# How to properly import new module to Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to import infinite-scroll module to my vue project, but the console says, that ".use" is an error.

console error:

[image: console error]

main.js:

[image]

I have no idea what to do. But I really want an infinite scroll in my app.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this *would* be the correct syntax to use

```js
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(infiniteScroll).mount('#app')
```

**However**, the library [vue-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/ElemeFE/vue-infinite-scroll) is only compatible with Vue 2, so even with correct syntax, you can't install it in a Vue 3 app.  For that you'll need to [find something else](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue+3+infinite+scroll)

Comment: About the "app" syntax, this was created by default when I typed 'vue create . ' in console before the project started. But, thanks for advice! Also, thanks for info about `vue-infinite-scroll`. You have saved my life.